# Looking for a script to convert a filename with backslashes into a directory structure with files

Tags: filenames, rename

We are currently testing a new application on Linux that previously worked on Windows.  It appears there were some hard coded paths in the program and a bunch of test files with long filenames with backslashes were created. For example:

```
directory\subdirectory\subdirectory\subdirectory\filename.ext
```

I need to take these files, create the directory they were supposed to be in and move them there. So, for example, the file above should actually be:

```
directory/subdirectory/subdirectory/subdirectory/filename.ext
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have a directory full of files all of which have these long names.  I want to split on the \ and then use all the elements to create a directory path and move the files into that new path.

Comment: `mkdir -p "$(printf '%s\n' "directory\sub1\sub2\sub3\fname.ext" | tr '\\' '/')"`

Comment: I need it to determine the file path based on the filename,

Comment: Did you try out the command provided to you?

Comment: @RakeshSharma i) please don't post answers as comments. ii) that won't actually work. It will create the *directory* `directory/sub1/sub2/sub3/fname.ext`, but the OP want the file `fname.ext` in the directory `directory/sub1/sub2/sub3`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rename *all* files whose name contains a `\`, you can do:

```
for file in *\\*; do 
    dir="$(dirname -- "${file//\\/\/}")"
    filename="${file##*\\}"
    mkdir -p -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"/"$filename"
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in *\\*`: The glob `*\\*` matches any file or directory name in the current directory whose name contains a `\`. Because the `\` is also the escape character, we need to escape it so it is treated as a literal. That's why we can't just use `*\*`.

  Then, this will iterate over all files and directories whose name contains a `\`, saving each of them as `$file`.
- `dir="$(dirname "${file//\\/\/}")"` : `${file//\\/\/}` will print the current file name with all `\` replaced with `/`. The escaping `\\` and `\/`) is needed since both `\` and `/` are special characters. `dirname` prints the directory a file is contained in. For example, `dirname /path/to/file` will return `/path/to`. Therefore, `$dir` will be the target directory we will want to move this file to.
- `filename=${file##*\\}` : the file's name, with everything before the last `\` removed. This is the actual file name and will be saved as `$filename`.
- `mkdir -p "$dir"` : create the target directory and all its parents. The `-p` makes `mkdir` create the parent directories (without it `mkdir foo/bar` will not work unless `foo/` already exists) and also makes it ignore errors about the directory already existing.
- `mv "$file" "$dir"/"$filename"` : the final step, move the file to the right location.

Comment: This almost worked.  Created all the files and folders, but it kept the backslashes.  Thanks you so much for doing this.

Comment: @AndyP you're welcome but it kept the backslashes? How do you mean? If it created the files, it can't have kept the backslashes. The `mv` command *moves* files, so always removes its source. Are you running this on some weird filesystem perhaps?

Comment: All my directory names end with a \ at the end.  My directors list shows 2016\ and 2017\ as the first level directory names.  Subdirectores seem to show backslahes also.

Comment: @AndyP that doesn't make sense to me. I tested this by creating a set of files using the command `touch directory{1,2}\\subdir{1,2}\\subsubdir{1,2}\\filename{1,2}.{txt,jpg}`. Those seem to be exactly like what you described and my script worked as expected. I suspect you might not have copied it correctly. It's hard to debug in the comments though. Come into our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and ping me `@terdon` if you like, and I can have a look.

Comment: @tedron I"ll try it again in a minute.  I'm done for the day in a half hour, so this may have to wait till the morning.

Comment: @AndyP fair enough, but I can't promise I'll be here in the (your) morning

Comment: I understand.  I'm grateful for all the help I have gotten

Answer (score 1):

```
prename 'mkdir $` while s[\\][/]' *\\*
```

Where `prename` is the Perl utility, sometimes called `rename` also. The basic model of operation of this command is that the filenames that need to changed are provided to it via it's commandline, in our case `*\\*` will feed all filenames that have at least a backslash in their names.

Then the code present in the single quotes is applied on the filenames one-by-one and what results in `$_` is the new filename.

We setup a `while` loop which progressively changes a backslash a time to a slash and creates a directory pointed to by the $` var which is the pre-match portion of the string.

When we come out of the while loop the `$_` contains
   directory/subdirectory/subdirectory/subdirectory/filename.ext
and this is what the original is renamed to now that the dirs/subdirs all now exist.